# Media Upload Not Triggering for Crowded Media Path

Tags: media-library

In Sitecore 8.2, we have an item template featuring an image field.  The preferred workflow for creating an instance of this template is the use the Browse trigger on the image field and the Upload dialogs in the ensuing displays.  A problem has arisen where this goes fine until the user clicks the final Upload link/button, at which point, in certain environments, nothing happens; that is, it sits indefinitely at 0%.

A contributing problem is likely that the most common destination folder rarely gets cleaned up, particularly in development and staging environments.  In at least one environment it contains thousands of images.

Is the "overcrowding" of the destination folder enough to account for this behavior?  In any case, is there an accepted limit on how many items should reside in a given Media Library folder?

Comment: 100 items is what is suggested. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838143/avoiding-100-item-limit-in-the-media-library . Check your browser network tab in developer tools - I suspect there are some timeouts there

Comment: So, the dev tools highlighted a different source for my problem:  in uploader.js, at or about line 440, it tries to execute this code:

`var token = _sc.Helpers.antiForgery.getAntiForgeryToken();`

which fails because _sc.Helpers.antiForgery is, apparently, undefined.  Any chance this is a known problem with a known solution?

Comment: That should be another question :)